# How to organize/sort alias mails?

Tags: mail.app, email, alias

I have one mail account with 3 aliases. I am wondering if there is any way to separate them from one mailbox to 4 individual mailboxes?

Is there a "hidden feature" I do not know about that lets you use Smart Mailboxes for that? Are there any tips/ideas as to how I can organize them in a nicer and cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is doesn’t matter if you use a mail sorting rule (found in Mail’s preferences) to *move* the mail to the target mailbox of your choice or if you create a smart mailbox to *display* the mail which will keep staying inside the inbox. All you need is a rule of this type:

```
Any recipient is aliasname@maildomain.com
```

This should separate your mails to different mailboxes as you described.